# Reading json file in C++

Tags: c++, io

I was trying to read JSON files using ifstream in C++.

but the code crashes and shows this **error** :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::detail::parse_error'
  what():  [json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at line 1, column 1: syntax error while parsing value - unexpected end of input; expected '[', '{', or a literal
```

I am storing input filenames first in jsonInputs vector and then trying to read the files using loop. Here is the source code :

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include "json.hpp" // nlohmann
using namespace std;

using json = nlohmann::json;
vector<string> jsonInputs;
vector<json> userdata;

bool validInput(string name){
  return name.find(".json") != -1;
}

void getInputFiles(){
  DIR *folder;
  struct dirent *entry;
  int files = 0;

  folder = opendir("data");
  if(folder == NULL){
      perror("Unable to read user data");
      exit(1);
  }

  jsonInputs.clear();
  while( (entry=readdir(folder)) ){
      files++;
      if(validInput(entry->d_name))
        jsonInputs.push_back(entry->d_name);
//      printf("File %3d: %s\n",files, entry->d_name);
  }

  closedir(folder);
}

void readfile(string filename){
  ifstream infile(filename);
  json inobj;
  infile >> inobj;
  userdata.push_back(inobj);
}

int main(){

  getInputFiles();
  for(int i = 0; i < jsonInputs.size(); i++){
      readfile(jsonInputs[i]);
  }

  for(auto Json : userdata){
    cout << Json << endl;
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: using [nlohmann's json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library for json

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the issue is -- one of the files is empty rather than containing a valid JSON object as the code expects. So what's your question?

Comment: but none of the input file is invalid. i think **infile >> inobj** line is causing the problem, but don't know why and how to resolve the issue.

Comment: You have some files and one of them causes a problem. **You need to show us contents of that file**.  We cannot possibly divine it out of thin air.

Comment: Input files are all ok. The problem lies within *readfile* function in **infile >> inobj** line. If i run the code commenting this line everything works fine.

Comment: The file may have a validity certificate signed by Niels Lohmann himself, it doesn't matter one little bit. See [mcve]. Note the question must contain everything needed to reproduce the problem. This includes any input files.